# Why Inertia is rendering views in Laravel 8, React and Vite?

Tags: php, laravel-8, vite, inertiajs

I have installed **Laravel 8** and **Inertia** with **vite** and **React**, following the documentation [serve side](https://inertiajs.com/server-side-setup) and [client side](https://inertiajs.com/client-side-setup)

My requirement is to have **Laravel 8** and **Inertia** with **Reactjs** using **Vite**.

I am facing an issue of in `/resources/views/app.blade.php`. It is not rendering raw output as follow

[image]

**web.php**

```php
use Inertia\Inertia;


Route::get('/', function () {    
    return Inertia::render('Homepage');
});
```

**app.blade.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    @viteReactRefresh 
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.jsx'])
    @inertiaHead
  </head>
  <body>
    @inertia
  </body>
</html>
```

**vite.config.js**

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react(),
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.jsx',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),

    ],
});
```

**package.json**

```js
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build && vite build --ssr"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.4",
        "alpinejs": "^3.4.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.49",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.4.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.4.6",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.64.2",
        "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@inertiajs/react": "^1.0.9",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "vite": "^4.4.9"
    }
}
```